# Footnotes appearing with references in revtex4.1

Tags: formatting, footnotes, revtex

I am using `revtex4-1`, but footnotes comes with references. How footnotes can be arranged below text instead of references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `nofootinbib` class option:

```
\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\footnote{a test footnote.}

\end{document}
```